# Question about Matrix and Eigenvector / Eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A ∈ M_{n×n}(\mathbb{R})$. Prove or provide a counter example:

If $n = 2$ and $A$ has exactly one eigenvalue $λ$, then $A$ is similar to $\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda  & 0\\ 
0 & \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}$ or to $\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda  & 1\\ 
0 & \lambda 
\end{bmatrix}$.

I understand that this is true, but I do not have any clue on how to prove it.

I will appreciate your help very much!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *Hint*: geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you, can you explain more please?